# SYMFONY PHP DOCTRINE ORM - Remove property from an entity using maker bundle (php bin/console make:entity)

Tags: php, symfony, orm, doctrine

I have created an Entity using the maker bundle.

I would like to remove from my Entity a property using the maker bundle (php bin/console make:entity).

Ok, I might do that be editing the file where my entity class is defined, but I would like to use the maker bundle if such a possibility exists.

Thank you.

Comment: You cannot remove a property using the maker bundle, just remove the property and getters/setters and you should be fine when making a new migration